# Controlling Non-Procedural Texture in Particle System with Color Ramp

Tags: particles

A problem with Particle System texture control: It seems like when I use a Blender generated procedural noise, the color ramp is able to affect it, but when I use a custom texture, color ramp makes the the texture completely black or white.

Example 1: Procedural Noise affects particle density and size and reacts to a color ramp option (CORRECT)

[image]

Example 2: Non-Procedural Texture affects particle density and size. (CORRECT) but DOESN'T react properly to the color ramp once color ramp option is ticked on (WRONG).

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me with this? I need to use just one hand painted textures to control multiple particles systems with an offset (and that offset can be achieved by a color ramp). But it looks like it doesn't work. I will appreciate all the help I can get :) Thank you!

Comment: Absolutely, can reproduce. Depending on what you want to do, you could get around with Geometry Nodes? I can't see a lot of development work going into the legacy texture system